# Is there any way to limit json request items?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, api, python-requests

Is there any way to limit how many items I want to get from a `JSON` request?

the code I use:

```py
import json
import requests

url = 'https://api.github.com/users'
response = json.loads((requests.get(url)).text)
```

the `JSON` response may have thousands of different items and getting all of it may take so much time but I want to get for example `first 100` and be done so fast, is there any optimal way to do this?

Comment: It won’t be as confident as you want, but you might look at a stream reader like this: https://pypi.org/project/json-stream/

Comment: Simple answer - No. Because if you don't read **all** of the JSON data you won't have a valid JSON structure. Also, better would be: *response = requests.get(url).json()*

Comment: @PatrickM Thanks for the suggestion, I will check it

Comment: @LancelotduLac thanks for the recommendation, I think there has to be a way or something because the items inside the JSON data are iterative, and some APIs services have the same problem and give you the whole data at the first GET request.

Comment: @AmirShamsi Some APIs will accept a parameter that can be used to limit the number of "records" that will be returned. The API you're using accepts a per_page query parameter (default is 30). You can also use a so-called "link header" as documented on Github

Comment: @LancelotduLac Yes, GitHub API is just an example, and as you said *some* APIs have that option but I'm dealing with an API that doesn't have something like a query limit.